# Who does write apache2 PID on Debian 8

Tags: debian, init.d

I am a bit lost: who is in-charge to write the apache2 PID in Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)?

I think `/etc/init.d/apache2` invokes 
`/usr/sbin/apache2ctl` which in turn calls
`/usr/sbin/apache2`.

But in which stage the PID is written? Can you enlight me with the involved code snippet?

Comment: Isn't jessie using `systemd`?

Comment: some services are still working in legacy mode. See  #798430 wishlist on bugs.debian.org.